# Where should I use non-JSX syntax in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS now-a-days. I am going through JSX syntax while working on React.
I know that by using JSX it is a concise and familiar syntax for defining tree structures with attributes.
Which makes code easier to understand?

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
Var ReactComponent = React.createClass({
    Render: function(){
    Return (

    <ul className = “my-list">
            &ltli&gtFirst Text Content &lt/li&gt
            &ltli&gtSecond Text Content &lt/li&gt
    </ul>

);
}
});
```

Without JSX syntax

```
Var ReactComponent = React.createClass({
    Render: function(){
        Return(

    var child1 = React.createElement('li', null, 'First Text Content');
    var child2 = React.createElement('li', null, 'Second Text Content');
    var root = React.createElement('ul', { className: 'my-list' }, child1, child2);

    );
    }
    ));
```

Can anyone guide me if JSX syntax is easy and so convenient for React Implementation, then what are the situation where to use non-JSX syntax component in React?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's your personal choice to adopt JSX or not to. JSX is so popular while writing React apps, because it makes code concise, more readable and yes, maintainable of course. If you want to write React without JSX, surely you can and there are no particular cases where you must/must not use JSX. But as your app grows, you'll discover that your codebase is increasing in complexity because of non-JSX syntax.

Just for simplicity and maintainability on a longer run, use JSX. For just trying or learning, as a matter of fact, you can write React in pure JS.